# Angular filter ul based on jQuery appended li

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So I'm quite new to angular but for my project I'm using both angular and jQuery.

I am currently making an ajax api call that loops through all responses and appends an `<li>` to populate a `<ul>`.

My code:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://127.0.0.1/example/api/example',
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
})
.done(function(data) {
   console.log("success");
   $.each(data.response, function(k, v) {
   $('.my-ul').append('<li>'+data.response[k].name+'</li>')
   });
})
```

So this produces a list, and now I would like to filter that list using angular and an input field.

I currently have an input field:

```
    <ul class=".my-ul">
       <div layout-gt-sm="row">
          <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
            <label id="client-label">Client</label>
            <input id="client-input" ng-model="client-list">
          </md-input-container>
      </div>
    </ul>
```

Angular:

```
angular
.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ngRoute'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

So how can I filter the `<li>` that is within `.my-ul` using the input field `client-input`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is completely backwards to how you work with angular. You should be adding the data to the scope model and let angular create the elements. Find some tutorials that use `ng-repeat` ( most basic tutorials will including the one on documentation site)

Comment: Post your associated controller code please.

Comment: @ShaohaoLin I added my angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can convert your code from jQuery to Angular. What you have to is just fetch the HTTP request using `$http.get()` in Angular.

```
angular
.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ngRoute'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('127.0.0.1/example/api/example').success(function(data){
      $scope.clients = data;
    });
});
```

Also you should follow **tdragon**'s answer for the HTML but you need to add the filter to it.

```
<div layout-gt-sm="row">
  <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label id="client-label">Client</label>
    <input id="client-input" ng-model="searchclient">
  </md-input-container>
</div>
<ul class=".my-ul">
  <li ng-repeat="client in clients | filter: searchclient">{{client.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

I will definitely recommend you to learn Angular 1 with the official tutorial [PhoneCat](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial). It explains how to fetch a GET request and display in the list with search ability.

`$http.get()` is one way that make an $ajax call in Angular, after successfully retrieve the data from url `127.0.0.1/example/api/example`, you assign it to `$scope.clients`, which you can access this `clients` variable in the front-end.

Comment: Thank you. I seem to get an error of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` on the line of the `$http.get`.. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Katie check the updated angular code. I make a mistake, sorry.

Comment: I am also getting an error `Expression 'client-list' is non-assignable. Element: {1}`. Would you know why that is happening?

Comment: Change `ng-model="client-list"` to `ng-model="searchclient"`, at the same time change the filter to the cor response variable.

Comment: Last question: In my ajax call you can see that I am looping through `data.response` in order to get the `data.response[k].name` and in the example you provided you only put `data`, how can I loop through `data.response` to get the name of each response? Thank you

Comment: @Katie Usually it is much easier to just ask a new question, since you have more space to explain what the question is. Also, if you add info in the comment later, this confuses readers and nobody will come back to look at your question in the comment session. And if my solution does solve your problem, please consider upvote and accept. It is good for the community.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you are not supposed to put `div` element as a `ul` immediate child.

Second of all - playing jQuery and Angular together is not a good idea. If you are using Angular, you should use jQuery in directives only.

In your situation, your HTML should look like this:

```
<div layout-gt-sm="row">
    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
        <label id="client-label">Client</label>
        <input id="client-input" ng-model="client-list">
    </md-input-container>
</div>
<ul class=".my-ul">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

You should retrieve `items` in your controller using e.g. `$http` services, instead of jQuery AJAX. The filtering you can do in `ng-repeat` directive. You can check the AngularJS home page - there is a sample very similar to your needs.